# fix the error -> "Could not cast value of type 'SecondViewController' to 'FirstViewController'"

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

Today I split my storyboards and now I'm getting an error and I don't know how to fix it.

I have 1 storyboard (Products) which contains all my UIViewControllers from first Tab and I have another storyboard (Cart) which contains all my UIViewControllers from the second tab.
I've set the StoryBoard Entry Point to all navigations controller, I set references in the MainStoryboard, I set the correct storyboard destination for each StoryBoard Reference, I really don't know what I did wrong.

Here is the error which I get it when I launch the app:

```
"Could not cast value of type 'ShoppingLand.CartViewController' (0x10d72a780) to 'ShoppingLand.ProductsViewController' (0x10d72a8c0)."
```

Here is my function where is crashing (is crashing on first line):

```
// Append the selectedProducts into productsInCartArray using the TabBarController
    func fetchSelectedProducts() {
        let firstTabVC = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! ProductsViewController)
        productsInCartArray = firstTabVC.selectedProductsArray
        productPricesArray = firstTabVC.priceForSelectedProductsArray
        getProductsPhotosArray = firstTabVC.googlePhotosArray
        totalSum = productPricesArray.reduce(0, +)
    }
```

Here is a picture with my StoryBoards:

[image]

Thank you for your time !

Comment: looks like `let firstTabVC = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0])` is actually returning a `CartViewController `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error in a second after I swapped this 2 icons using drag and drop.
[image]

Thank you for your time !